# Fixed number of results biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to retrieve the search results using the following code for a query from pubmed via biopython

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import Medline

Entrez.email = "A.N.iztb@bobxx.com"
LIM = 3


def search(Term):
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pmc', term=Term, retmax=100000000)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    idlist = record["IdList"]
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db='pmc', id=idlist, rettype="medline", retmode="text")
    records = Medline.parse(handle)
    return list(records)
mydic=search('(pathological conditions, signs and symptoms[MeSH Terms]) AND (pmc cc license[filter]) ')
print(len(mydic))
```

No matter how many times I try, I get 10000 in the output. Tried different queries but I still get 10000. When I manually check how many results via browser I get random numbers.

What exactly is going wrong and how to ensure that I get the maximum results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only seem to be changing the `esearch` limit, but leave `efetch` alone (and the NCBI seems to default to a limit of 10000). You need to use the `retstart` and `retmax` arguments.

See the "*Searching for and downloading abstracts using the history*" example in the Biopython Tutorial, http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html or http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.pdf